# React and UI Libraries

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap, semantic-ui-react

I am just getting started with react and had a question regarding some of the UI libraries built for react.

Is it possible to include components from different libraries in my react project? For instance can I include a modal from bootstrap-react and a data table from semantic-ui-react? I believe this is possible, but are there any performance issues when doing this? Has anyone had any experience as such?

Any comments would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone with any help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no personal experience of using components from multiple UI libraries in one project.

You can include components from multiple UI libraries as long as the components don't conflict (e.g., use of same CSS selectors with different expectations). There should not be a major performance impact due to using two UI libraries. After all, the UI libraries just manipulate the virtual DOM, like any React component.

Generally speaking, I would recommend against the use of multiple UI libraries in one project. By using one library only, you get consistent look and behavior, and you need to learn to master only one library, which likely makes you more productive.

Comment: thanks heaps for that information, as I said I am really just starting out and trying to get my head around how to include css ui libraries into my project. Knowing that multiple UI libraries should not have a major impact on performace will give me a good chance to experiment a little bit. Any other comments would be very helpful.